# How do I place span elements before and after a paragraph with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have some text in HTML that changes frequently and I'm trying to place a span tag before and after it, but when I try to create a span element and add it before the text element it instead displays "[object HTMLSpanElement]"

What should I do so I can have a text element that has a separate span element on both sides of the text?

Desired output: `<span></span> <p id = "mytext"> <span></span>`

```js
function myFunction() {
  myText = document.getElementById("myText");
  var mySpan = document.createElement('span');
  mySpan.textContent = 'example';

  myText.textContent = mySpan;
}
```

```html
<p id="myText"> Example </p>

<button onclick="myFunction()"> Click Here </button>
```

Comment: The reason it shows `[object HTMLSpanElement]` is because you are assigning an object (mySpan) to a text field, and so JS is converting the object into its string representation.

Comment: Sorry, I updated the question to be more clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So if you want to inject a DOM element before another and after, you could use `before()` and `after()` methods. Here's documentation for [`after()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/after) and for [`before()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/before).

```js
function myFunction() {
    myText = document.getElementById("myText");
    var mySpanLeft = document.createElement('span');
    var mySpanRight = document.createElement('span');
    myText.before(mySpanLeft)
    myText.after(mySpanRight)
  }
```

```html
<p id = "myText"> Example </p>

<button onclick = "myFunction()"> Click Here </button>
```

Comment: OOOH, I see, okay, hold on, I will make the last final edit then.

Comment: @Tabogachi I edited my message and wiped the old one. Hope this now solves your problem.

Comment: Consider using just one new span here `const newSpan = document.createElement('span');
myText.before(newSpan); myText.after(newSpan)`

Comment: Not a problem @Tabogachi.

@MarkSchultheiss I don't think this would work as `before()` and `after()` would move the same instance of a span. Correct me if I'm wrong though.

Comment: @SnoopFrog ah yes; just a quick thought on my part late on a Friday :( alternate would be just enclose it I suppose `myText.before(document.createElement('span'))`

Comment: That could be done this way, yes @MarkSchultheiss. I did separate them because I assumed that OP wants to do something to those spans and not just leave them empty, it is possible that my assumption is wrong though.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a step-by-step approach that's fairly readable. I would also refactor to use an event listener instead of inline JavaScript, and to pass in an element to make the function reusable (always a worthy goal).

```js
function flankTextWithSpans(el) {
  const mySpan = document.createElement('span');
  const myText = el.textContent;

  el.replaceChildren();   // clear the element contents
  el.appendChild(mySpan); // append the empty span
  el.innerHTML += myText; // append the text
  el.appendChild(mySpan); // append the empty span again
}

document.querySelector('#myButton').addEventListener('click', () => {
  flankTextWithSpans(document.querySelector('#myText'));
});
```

```css
span {
  background: pink;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<p id="myText"> Example </p>

<button id="myButton"> Click Here </button>
```

Comment: Feels like this better answers the question as asked "add it inside the text element" than the currently accepted one.

Comment: Yeah, the question changed many times and _still_ has internal contradiction ("add it inside the text element" vs. the desired markup example showing the spans _outside_).

Comment: The "desired markup" also removes the `<p>` closing tag - which is valid HTML but still adds to the lack of clarity I agree;

Answer (score 1):

This is not a "perfect" example but you can either replace all or just wrap a word (or words)  this will have challenges if the element contains HTML already in some situations.

I was a bit confused initially by the question so I added a wrapper and a flanker example;

```js
function wrapper(word, element) {
  const rgxp = new RegExp(word, 'g');
  const repl = '<span class="my-class">' + word + '</span>';
  element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.replace(rgxp, repl);
}

function flanker(word, element) {
  const rgxp = new RegExp(word, 'g');
  const repl = '<span class="my-class"></span>' + word + '<span class="my-class"></span>';
  element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.replace(rgxp, repl);
}

function callWrapper() {
  const myText = document.getElementById("myText");
  wrapper("Example", myText);
  flanker("guys", myText);
}
```

```css
.my-class {
  background-color: yellow;
  border: solid green 2px;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<p id="myText"> Example fun guys </p>

<button onclick="callWrapper()"> Click Here </button>
```